# using System.ComponentModel.Description Vs /// Description Comment Usage in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, comments

**Is it a programming practice of adding *Model_1* descriptions to all classes or is it specific to UI elements?**

For example, I found this code on [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/design-tools/expression-studio-3/cc295235(v=expression.30)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

### ***Model_1***

`[Description("Represents a custom button control that responds to a Click event. Displays an image using a custom Source property if the Source property is bound to an Image in the template.")]`

`public class ImageButton : Button`

How is the different from?

### ***Model_2***

`/// <summary>`

`///Represents a custom button control that responds to a Click event. Displays an image using a custom Source property if the Source property is bound to an Image in the template.`

`///</summary>`

`public class ImageButton : Button`

**Where is the correct place for using both or the *Model_1* description specifically?**

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no other answers here is what my research says!

##### Model 1 - Description Attribute

Description attribute is for providing a brief summary of the behaviour of the WPF UI element

Use cases are targeted against the UI elements exclusively.

##### Model 2 - XML Comments

The standard way of documenting C# code, even the UI elements

In general, it's a good practice to use XML comments to document C# code, as they provide more detailed information that can be used to generate API documentation. However, the Description attribute can be useful for providing a concise summary of the purpose and behaviour of a UI element in a WPF application.